# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, omdbapi

[Link to the TypeError Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neoUd.png)

The App was working fine yesterday.
I deleted the project and cloned from Github.com. Still it won't work.
Here's the link to the code:
[Link to the Github Project](https://github.com/sPreet247/Movie-app)

```js
import React from 'react';

function SearchMovies(props) {
  const FavoriteComponent = props.favoriteComponent;
  return (
    <>
      {props.movies.map((movie, index) => (
        <div>
          s<img src={movie.Poster} alt='movie'></img>
          <div onClick={() => props.handleFavoritesClick(movie)}>
            <FavoriteComponent />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default SearchMovies;
```

Comment: Please post the code directly here before you get downvoted into oblivion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SearchMovies` component try using null propagation to avoid that error.

`{props.movies?.map((movie, index) => (...`

```
import React from 'react';

function SearchMovies(props) {
  const FavoriteComponent = props.favoriteComponent;
  return (
    <>
      {props.movies?.map((movie, index) => (
        <div>
          s<img src={movie.Poster} alt='movie'></img>
          <div onClick={() => props.handleFavoritesClick(movie)}>
            <FavoriteComponent />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default SearchMovies;
```

Working App after correction: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-luzeaq?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: You are welcome. I also fixed the bug with the localStorage in the second useEffect hook which was causing ```favorites not an iterable``` error. now everything is working as It should. 
Happy coding.